# shell script to move files improperly concatenating strings

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I was trying to write a shell script to move some files for me, but I made the mistake of running said script without double checking the variables it was using first.

Here's the script I'm writing:

```
#!/bin/bash
# move the war files to jboss in one thing

JBOSS_DEPLOY="/cust/env/local/cust/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/deploy/"

echo JBOSS_DEPLOY

TRADITIONAL="$JBOSS_DEPLOYmyProject.war"
NOSQL="$JBOSS_DEPLOYmyProjectNoSql.war"

echo $TRADITIONAL

mv myProject.war $TRADITIONAL
mv myProjectNoSql.war $NOSQL
```

The echos were for debugging purposes. It seems that `"$JBOSS_DEPLOYmyProject.war"` became `".war"`. What do I need to fix to properly concatenate those strings into a new variable?

I'm also a little curious where the files actually went. Clearly they would've overwritten each other, but there should be one file named `".war"` somewhere, right? Where would it be?

EDIT: I found where it got put. I didn't realize the `"."` would hide it from view. Now I just need to know how to properly concatenate strings with no space!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bash has no way of telling where a variable name ends and where plaintext starts, unless you provide it with a hint:

```sh
"$FOObar"   # variable named  "FOObar"
# v.s.
"${FOO}bar"  # variable named "FOO" and some plaintext "bar"
```

Comment: Yup, that's all I needed. Thanks!

Comment: +1. Alternatively: `TRADITIONAL="$JBOSS_DEPLOY/myProject.war"`